# Controlled nested looping

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, permutation

I have the nested loops that nested (r=) 3 times. Each loop running for (n=) 5 times.

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        for (k=0; k<n; k++)
        //
    }
}
```

But how do we do the nesting dynamically at run time. Say we know it should be nested r times. Each loop running n times. I thought something like recursion but it goes indefinitely.

```
funloop (int r)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
          //
          if (r < 3)
              funloop (r++);
          else
              return;
      }
}
```

Please let me know how this could be done? I couldn't find a sources online.

Comment: Can you post your exact code for the second case?  The logic you have is close to being right and shouldn't loop infinitely, but without seeing the actual code I can't provide a more detailed explanation of the underlying bug.

Comment: Your code was completely wrong, since you used 3 times i in the first example (now i,j,k) and the if-statement in the 2nd example was followed by two expressions, not nested in a block. So there was a dangling else. If you post compilable code, such errors won't happen. The second example is imho still wrong, because the comment marks where the real code should be, but this should just be in the else-block (which then needs curly braces too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is just to collapse it to one for loop:

```
for(i=0; i<pow(n, r); i++) {
}
```

That can however make it difficult to access the loop counters, if you need them, but that can be done mathematically. For example, the innermost loop counter variable value is given by :

```
int c = i % n;
```

You could have an array of such counters and determine the values with similar equations, or you can just increment them, when required, e.g.:

```
void iterate(int r, int n) {
  int i, rc, *c = malloc(sizeof(int) * r);

  memset(c, 0, sizeof(int) * r);
  for(i = 0; i < pow(n, r); i++) {

    // code here, using loop counters in the 'c' array, where c[0] is counter
    // for the outer loop, and c[r - 1] is the counter for the innermost loop

    // update the counters
    rc = r;
    while(rc > 0) {
      rc--;
      c[rc]++;
      if(c[rc] == n) {
        c[rc] = 0;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  free(c); 
}
```

Comment: Oh man, just what I was about to answer.:P But one thing, we code a lot alike.

Comment: Thank you. My original problem was to code for permutation with repetition. Finally got it working.

Comment: Using `pow` for the upper bound of the loop looks weird to me. In general I think one should be more careful with the types for the loop variables. These can easily overflow. Using `uintmax_t` would be more appropriate, I think.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know the depth of the recursion statically, the most common approach is to use recursion to represent the looping.  For example, suppose that you need to have d levels of nesting of loops that all need to iterate k times.  Then you could implement that using recursion of this form:

```
void RecursivelyNestIterations(unsigned d, unsigned k) {
    /* Base case: If the depth is zero, we don't need to iterate. */
    if (d == 0) return;

    /* Recursive step: If we need to loop d times, loop once, calling the
     * function recursively to have it loop d - 1 times.
     */
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
         /* Recurse by looping d - 1 times using the same number of iterations. */
         RecursivelyNestIterations(d - 1, k);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have a code to print nPr selections:How would i change it to recursive model?                                               `#define n 4 
#define r 2
void main(void) {
  
 int x[r];
 int *list = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);  
 int count=0, i,j,k;
 for(i=0; i<n; i++)
  list[i] = i+1;
 for(x[0]=0;x[0]<n;x[0]++)
 {
  for(x[1]=0;x[1]<n;x[1]++)
  {
   printf("\n %d %d",list[x[0]],list[x[1]]); 
   count++;
  }
 }
}`

Comment: @John- If you want help with that code, then you should post it as a separate question.  Also, I think you should try working this out for yourself as an exercise.  Try thinking about it recursively - how do you make the problem smaller?  How do you combine the smaller solutions into a larger solution?

Comment: Actually I had been trying for a recursive solution from the beginning.But found it hard and left it. Maybe I'll try harder. :) if i fail again i'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `if (r) funloop(r-1);` in the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static int n = 3;

void _funloop(int cur,int total)
{
    if(cur!=total)
    {
        for(int cnt=0;cnt!=n;++cnt)
        {
            fprintf(stdout,"%d::%d\n",cur,cnt);
        }

        _funloop(cur+1,total);
    }
}

void funloop(int total)
{
    _funloop(0,total);
}

int main()
{
    funloop(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that doesn't use recursion is discussed in this Tip
[link]http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/759707/Generating-dynamically-nested-loops
The code is in C++ and require # for the include and define statements

```
include <iostream>
define MAXROWS 9
define MAXVALUES 9

using namespace std;
char display[] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

int main() {

int arrs[MAXROWS];  // represent the different variables in the for loops

bool status = false;

for (int r=0;r<MAXROWS;r++)
    arrs[r] = 0;  // Initialize values

while (!status) { 

    int total = 0;
    // calculate total for exit condition
    for (int r=0;r<MAXROWS;r++)
        total +=arrs[r];
    // test for exit condition
    if (total == (MAXVALUES-1)*MAXROWS)
        status = true;

    // printing
    for (int r=0;r<MAXROWS;r++)
        cout << display[arrs[r]]; // print(arrs[r])
    cout << endl;  // print(endline)

    // increment loop variables
        bool change = true;
    int r = MAXROWS-1;  // start from innermost loop
    while (change && r>=0) {
        // increment the innermost variable and check if spill overs
        if (++arrs[r] > MAXVALUES-1) {        
            arrs[r] = 0;  // reintialize loop variable
            // Change the upper variable by one
            // We need to increment the immediate upper level loop by one
            change = true;
        }
        else
            change = false; // Stop as there the upper levels of the loop are unaffected

        // We can perform any inner loop calculation here arrs[r]

        r=r-1;  // move to upper level of the loop

    }

}
```